# Is Peter chamor done if the owner of the first born donkey is a kohen or Levite

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, yoreh-deah, levites-leviyim, peter-chamor

According to Halacha, if a first born male donkey is owned by a kohen or Levite is Pidyon peter chamor required? Or no is it exempt because of the owner’s status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are exempt. (Mishna Bekhorot 1:1)